# Using jQuery to Edit Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well I'm trying to make jQuery edit my body when a link is clicked. So far, all that it does is make the Link Fade but background wont change on the  I don't understand why, maybe you guys can help with that.

```
    <div id="navbar_wrapper">
        <div id="nav_title">
            Kitty <small> "<? echo $information[array_rand($information)]; ?>" </small>
        </div>
        <div id="nav_links">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <a href="#" id="activate">Download</a>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#activate').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut()
    $('body').css('background: red;')
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to this:

```
$('body').css('background', 'red')
```

if you want to do then you can choose this in the callback function in the fadout()

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
   $('body').css('background', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong to make use of the property css you need this structure:

```
$('body').css('background' , 'red')
```

The structure is related to :

```
.css('propertyname' , 'propertyvalue')
```

Check more [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this was great help!

Comment: you also can use the `:` but is for define multiple css properties and need other elements

Comment: ...or a map `css({background: 'red'})`

Comment: Yep all is more explained on the direct link to the jquery Api